# Microsoft SQL convert varchar to date, 101, and return blank for null

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, null

I need to return a `varchar` date field as 101 datetime while also returning blank field for `null` values.

Currently using this:

```
convert(varchar,try_cast (COALESCE([Col_106],'') as date), 101) as Date_of_Death
```

but this is returning a default value of `01/01/1900` when the date is `NULL`. How do I get this to be blank?

I also tried:

```
Date_of_Death2 = isnull(convert(varchar(10),col_106, 101),'')
```

but the date function, 101, is not being recognized and not formatting the date how I need it.

Thanks!

Comment: `TRY_CONVERT` is your friend.

Comment: Please show some examples of what the string looks like.  You should also learn the lesson of not storing dates as strings.

Comment: There is no blank date in ANSI SQL, there is NULL.

Comment: Yeah I didn't create the database, just have to deal with it. The date field is stored as: (varchar(20), NULL)

Comment: While it is of course true that storing date values as strings is wrong in the first place, this sould work: `with a as
(
select cast(null as dateTime) as d
union all
select getdate()
),
b as 
(
select cast(d as dateTime) dString
from a
)
select isnull(convert(varchar(10),cast(dString as dateTime),101),'') from b`

Comment: *"The date field is stored as: (varchar(20), NULL) "* converting a `varchar` to a `varchar` wioth a style code does nothing. the style codes are for coverting *from* a `varchar` to a different data type or from a different data type to a `varchar`. Telling us that your "date" column isn't a `date` should have been information you gave us in yoru question from the start. Fix the design, and change the data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no blank date in SQL Server, whenever you want to cast a blank varchar to a date it would get the default date of 1/1/1900. Instead you can coalesce() later:

```
select COALESCE(CONVERT(varchar,TRY_CAST( [Col_106] as date), 101),'') as Date_Of_Death2 ...
```